# How to implement a color-prioritized treemap?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, treemap

What would be the best way to implement (preferably using d3.js) a color prioritized treemap as presented in this blog post: http://groupvisual.io/?s=treemap?

[image]

Comment: You would probably start with the existing treemap implementation.